# UserDefault boolean is always false

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've `UISwitch`, with that switch I give variable `userDefaultYvelaSachmeli` its own bool value, if `UISwitch` `isOn` I set it to true, otherwise false. Switch works fine, but it doesn't save value with `UserDefaults`. Whenever I try to restart the xCode Simulator, values of `userDefaultYvelaSachmeli` is `false` even If I set it true before restart. I don't understand why it doesn't work, any solution will be appericated

```swift
// userDefaultYvelaSachmeli is a global variable
var userDefaultYvelaSachmeli:Bool = true {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userDefaultYvelaSachmeli, forKey: "Yvelaferi")
    }
}
// inside view controller
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if defaults.object(forKey: "Yvelaferi") != nil {
            userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = defaults.bool(forKey: "Yvelaferi")
        }
        self.yvelaSachmeliSwitch.isOn = userDefaultYvelaSachmeli
}
    @IBAction func yvelaSachmeliDidChange(_ unfiltered: UISwitch) {
        if unfiltered.isOn {
            userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = true
        } else {
            userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `IBAction` connected, that means is it called at all ? By the way you can write shorter `userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = unfiltered.isOn`. And a `Bool` in `UserDefaults` is never `nil`, the default value is `false`.

Comment: @vadian Yes, it is connected and also called. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Don't use a global variable.  Make it a property of your view controller.   And there is no need for the `if` in the switch handler.  You can just assign `isOn` directly to the variable

Answer (score -1):

Don’t use global variable. Instead of it create a struct for constant

Inside ViewDidLoad

```
let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Yvelaferi")
self.yvelaSachmeliSwitch.isOn = status
```

Inside IBAction

```
@IBAction func yvelaSachmeliDidChange(_ unfiltered: UISwitch) {
    if unfiltered.isOn {
            //userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Yvelaferi")
    } else {
            //userDefaultYvelaSachmeli = false
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "Yvelaferi")
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```